# Automated Maintainence/"We will be back" page

Tags: php, linux

We are running some sites that receive decent traffic and occasional leechers that hog the resources and make our servers un-responsive, users making 100s and 1000s of requests from jumping IP addresses. This sometimes causes the server load to increase or server runs out of memory and needs a reboot.

We want to have a page that automatically pops up like "we will be back soon" when our server goes down or becomes unresponsive. How can this be configured?

We are running PHP on a linux server.

Comment: if your server is being rebooted, how are you going to serve the "being rebooted" page? :o

Comment: Was thinking if something can be done at a DNS level?

Comment: DNS points to an IP address.  In the time it would take for a monitoring system to notice that your server is down, make the DNS change to have the IP address point to a different host and then let the change propogate, your server would have rebooted long ago.  Use a reverse HTTP proxy running on a different host from your web server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suggestion would be to hide your traffic behind a reverse HTTP proxy.

We use [Pound](http://apsis.ch/pound) for precisely this purpose.  It receives HTTP/HTTPS requests on a public IP, then issues its own HTTP request to Apache running on localhost (or a private IP).  If Apache is unavailable, it returns a 500 error, which we can configure.

This lets us take down Apache while leaving an out-of-service notice in place.  It also allows us to put some interesting filtering in place; Pound is quite a bit quicker and easier to configure than Apache.

Your next big win by using a reverse proxy is that it is also a load balancer.  If instead of pointing to just one Apache instance, it points to two, running on different servers.  Then suddenly you have twice the capacity of a single server, hiding behind the same URL.  Pound take virtually no resources to run and can handle many thousands of hits per second.

Note that other options for a reverse proxy exist.  [nginx](http://wiki.nginx.org/), in addition to being a solid, uber-high-speed web server, is also a solid, uber-high-speed reverse proxy.  Harder to configure and maintain than Pound, but still a good option to consider.  You can also run another instance of Apache as a reverse proxy, though I wouldn't recommend it, with these other two better options available.

Comment: Pound seems to be our solution. Thanks!